# Fetch System Property in Automation script in Maximo

Tags: python, maximo

I would like to know how to fetch system property in an automation script. I do understand we can declare it as variable however I would like to know whether there is any other way since using it as a variable is causing error in scripting for integration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MXServer has 2 getProperty() methods. To get a public property's value, just pass in the name of the property. To get a private property's value, you'll also need to pass in a UserInfo.

Example in Jython:

```
from psdi.server import MXServer
maximo = MXServer.getMXServer()
publicProperty = maximo.getProperty("company.public.propertyname")
privateProperty = maximo.getProperty("company.private.propertyname",mbo.getUserInfo())
```

Comment: In the Jython Automation Script, is there a way to force a Live Refresh of the System Property retrieved using MXServer.getProperty()

Comment: To answer my own question here, I found that I could call `MXServer.reloadMaximoCache('MAXPROP', 'myPropName', False)`